# How can I create gcePD and link it as persistent volume to on-premise k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

How can I create gcePD (google persistent disk) and link it as persistent volume (pv) to on-premise kubernetes cluster?
It is required to resolve `persistentvolume-controller - no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set` message when I deployed some helm chart.

Please explain the steps for that. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, gave you some insights...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, GCE persistent disks are not exposed outside of GCE. Your servers need to be in GCE.

You could probably set a remote PV using [Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction), but unless you need them for low-performance storage, I'd be wary of the speed and latency if you don't have a direct connect pipe to the Azure cloud.

You could also set up a GCE disk shared filesystem with [Ceph](https://ceph.com/), [ScaleIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_EMC_ScaleIO), etc, but again you would be going across the public cloud if you don't have a private direct connect.

Comment: ok, @Rico you absolutely right.
If your Kubernetes cluster is running on Amazon’s AWS EC2, for example, you can use an awsElasticBlockStore volume to provide persistent storage for your pods. If your  cluster  runs  on  Microsoft  Azure,  you  can  use  the  
azureFile or the azureDisk volume. With gcePD and GCE the same. When you run your cluster elsewhere, you should use other types of volumes, depending on the underlying infrastructure.